# MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR not recognized on the Sony Xperia Z3 compact

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app that records audio and stores the audio files. It seems to work fine on every phone except the Sony Xperia Z3 compact. I found out that setting the output format of the MediaRecorder to MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR was the cause of the problem due to which the MediaPlayer was throwing an error. When change the output format to MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP it seems to work. The problem now is, I need the files to be in the amr format. Any ideas on why this problem exists and how I should proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

don't know about AMR but

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html

says

int RAW_AMR
This constant was deprecated in API level 16. Deprecated in favor of MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB

Oh. this is 2 year old question.